# Add movieclips within another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I am having trouble embedding a child object to a movieClip with code using AS3 and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to create a new movieclip with code and add it to the stage. I am then trying to embed dynamically created objects inside that movieclip. When I trace the objects it shows that they are on the stage and not embedded into the movieclip. I looked through the forums but I didn't find an answer. Below is a watered down version of the code I have.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;

    var btnAImage:Loader = new Loader();
    var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("btn_A.png");

    public function TextWithImage()
    {
        var TextField1:TextField = new TextField;
        var myText1:String = "TEXT FIELD 1";
        var BtnMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var btnPadding = 5;
        addChild(BtnMovieClip); //add new MC to stage

        btnAImage.load(image);
        BtnMovieClip.addChild(btnAImage); // no error gets thrown. I am trying to add the btnAImage inside of my BtnMovieClip.
        btnAImage.x = btnPadding; //I am able to reference the btnAImage without referencing the BtnMovieClip object.
        btnAImage.y = btnPadding;
        var screenW = stage.stageWidth;

        TextField1.height = 40;
        TextField1.width = 250;

        var textPadding = 5;

        var TextField1_fontFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat  ;
        TextField1_fontFormat.size = 40;
        TextField1_fontFormat.font = "TestFont";

        TextField1.defaultTextFormat = TextField1_fontFormat;

        BtnMovieClip.addChild(TextField1); // no error gets thrown. I am trying to add the text field inside of my BtnMovieClip.
        TextField1.text = myText1;

        TextField1.x = (btnAImage.width + textPadding);

        TextField1.y = textPadding;
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Now please explain *on the stage and not embedded into the movieclip* because word **embed** refers to font embedding so the problem is unclear.

Comment: Perhaps embed is not what I should have written. I am placing objects within a dynamically created movieclip. After doing some research, it appears that I am doing it correctly, however, my issue seems to be that I get a 0 when I check the width of my btnAImage with a trace.trace("btnAImage.width = " + btnAImage.width);
I tried to hardcode the width btnAImage.width = 35; but then the image disappears from the stage. Also, when I try to trace it's location my trace tells me that it is on the stage and not in my movie clip. I tried to change my container to a sprite, that didn't fix it.

Comment: Ah. That's because you need to wait till it loads. Initially it is empty and until the image is loaded (it's an asynchronous process so it happens **after** the initialization code is done) and width/height manipulations on an empty object **always** goes trouble unless you know exactly what you are doing and how to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I should have realized that myself.  I did note that when I tried to set the width of BtnMovieClip, it also disappears. It is my empty container.  Please note that I changed the code that creates BtnMovieClip from 
        var BtnMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
to
 var BtnContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

Comment: I figured it out!  Thank you all for your comments

This is what I did.
`
public var btnAImage:Loader;
  private function LoadImager()
  {
   btnAImage = new Loader();
   btnAImage.load(new URLRequest("btn_A.png"));
   btnAImage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, TextWithImage);
   
  }

public function TextWithImage(e:Event)
  {
   var BtnContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
   addChild(BtnContainer);
   btnAImage.width = 60;
`

Comment: Follow-up question....
Now that I have the image working as expected... I am trying to modify the width and height of my empty sprite called BtnContainer.   When I use BtnContainer.width = 300; the container does not appear and no error is thrown.

Comment: What it the initial width of **BtnContainer**? What is the expected result?

Comment: It's an empty sprite that is used to hold my other objects. There is no original width to it. That's why I am trying to set the width.

Comment: I realized my mistake... I was setting the width **before** I added objects to it.  Thanks for all of your help!!!

Comment: Good. Now, I bestow a piece of sacred knowledge upon you. While you cannot manipulate **width** and **height** of empty objects (they just collapse to 0x0), you still can set their **scaleX** and **scaleY**, thus if you know the size of the loading object, you actually can scale the container preemptively.

Comment: Thank you for bestowing your knowledge on me! You rock!!!

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't preloading my image so here's how I fixed it.  Thank you to Organis for the help!!!

```
    public var btnAImage:Loader;
    private function Question8_Answer()
    {
        trace("Question8_Answer() was called");
        btnAImage = new Loader();
        btnAImage.load(new URLRequest("btn_A.png"));
        btnAImage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, TextWithImage);

    }

public function TextWithImage()
{
    var TextField1:TextField = new TextField;
    var myText1:String = "TEXT FIELD 1";
    var BtnContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var btnPadding = 5;
    addChild(BtnMovieClip);

    BtnMovieClip.addChild(btnAImage); 
    btnAImage.x = btnPadding; 
    btnAImage.y = btnPadding;
    var screenW = stage.stageWidth;

    TextField1.height = 40;
    TextField1.width = 250;

    var textPadding = 5;

    var TextField1_fontFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat  ;
    TextField1_fontFormat.size = 40;
    TextField1_fontFormat.font = "TestFont";

    TextField1.defaultTextFormat = TextField1_fontFormat;

    BtnMovieClip.addChild(TextField1); // no error gets thrown. I am trying to add the text field inside of my BtnMovieClip.
    TextField1.text = myText1;

    TextField1.x = (btnAImage.width + textPadding);

    TextField1.y = textPadding;


    BtnContainer.width = 300;


}
```